# How to write a unittest for minimum timeout in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm trying to test a slow function.
It'll pass only when timeout is between 5s and 10s.
I'm using the `pytest` + `pytest-timeout` packages.
However it is for maximum timeout, not for minimum timeout.

```
import pytest
import time

def slow_func():
  time.sleep(8)

@pytest.mark.timeout(10)
def test_slow_func_max_timeout():
  slow_func()

# How to make sure it require >5s
def test_slow_func_min_timeout():
  slow_func()
```

How to write a test for the minimum timeout?

Comment: You could just code that up manually... `start = time()`, do tests, `self.assertGreater(time() - start, 5)`...

Comment: @metatoaster It's a good idea. Thanks